# ajax issue with setinterval javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube, setinterval

As part of a personal project, I play with Youtube API. You can see my website here : [www.lamusiquedelamour.com](http://www.lamusiquedelamour.com)

When the user arrives, it loads 10 videos. When the user reaches the last one, 30 seconds before the end of the video, it checks if there is a upcoming video. Is there isn't, it calls a function called `loadmore()` which launch an ajax request to retrieve the next 10 videos.

There is no implemented listener for the "Current Time" of a video in the Youtube API so what I do is launching a `YoutubePlayerInfo()` function with a setInterval when the first player is ready. (When a YT player is ready, it automatically calls a onYoutubePlayerReady function).

```
onYouTubePlayerReady: function(id) {
    if(!this.intervalYoutube) {
        inst = this;
        this.intervalYoutube = setInterval(inst.updatePlayerInfo, 250);
    }
}
```

And here is the interesting part of my `updatePlayerInfo` function, which is called every 250ms.

```
if( (inst.currentTrack().getElement().getDuration() - inst.currentTrack().getElement().getCurrentTime()) < 30) {
    if(!inst.isNext() && (inst.state != 3)) { 
        inst.state = 3;
        inst.loadmore();
    }
}
```

The isNext function only checks is there is a video in my video array. So when there is no upcoming video and my state is not at 3, i set the state at 3 and I launch my ajax. And here is the issue.

As the Ajax part is slow and there is a 250ms setInterval, the "loadmore" is fired between 1 and 3 times.

I think that it's waiting to get out of the if before really setting the state at 3. So if the ajax is fast, it will call loadmore once but that's not 100% sure.

The 3 loadmore calls are "parallel" and it enters the second and the third time before the end of the first one.

Here is what I think it's doing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l4nP.jpg

Do you know how to call my `loadmore()` only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `setTimeout` as opposed to `setInterval`... This way, the timer does not start until the previous cycle is finished. You'll just need to call `setTimeout` once to begin the cylce, and again to repeat the actions once the cycle is done.

```
onYouTubePlayerReady: function(id) {
        if(!this.intervalYoutube) {
            inst = this;
            this.intervalYoutube = setTimeout(inst.updatePlayerInfo, 250);
        }
}
```

---

```
if( (inst.currentTrack().getElement().getDuration() - inst.currentTrack().getElement().getCurrentTime()) < 30) {
    if(!inst.isNext() && (inst.state != 3)) { 
        inst.state = 3;
        inst.loadmore();
    }
    this.intervalYoutube = setTimeout(inst.updatePlayerInfo, 250);
}
```

---

`setTimeout(expression, timeout);` runs the code/function once after the timeout

`setInterval(expression, timeout);` runs the code/function in intervals, with the length of the timeout between them

Comment: Well, it seems to work perfectly. Thanks a lot for being way more smart than me :)